# Image quality changes(blurish) when I have select and crop image in android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I implemented code in android to select image from gallery and crop that image in imageview but cropped image is very blurish, how to display cropped image as it is

Here is my code:

ImageSelecter.java

```
public class ImageSelecter extends Activity {

private final int GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE=200;
private final int RESULT_CROP = 400;
String picturePath;
ImageView image_capture1;
Button btn_choose;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_choose=(Button)findViewById(R.id.choose_btn);
    image_capture1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    btn_choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Start Activity To Select Image From Gallery
            Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryUtil.class);
            startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
           }
         });

       }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");
            //perform Crop on the Image Selected from Gallery
            performCrop(picturePath);
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_CROP ) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

            // Set The Bitmap Data To ImageView
            image_capture1.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
              image_capture1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
    }
}

private void performCrop(String picUri) {
    try {
        //Start Crop Activity

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        File f = new File(picUri);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

        cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 280);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 280);

        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // display an error message
        String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
}
```

And the class to display gallery class is as follows

GalleryUtil.java

```
    public class GalleryUtil extends Activity {
    private final static int RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE = 100;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "GalleryUtil";

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    File photoFile = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
        //Pick Image From Gallery
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode){
        case RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE:

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                try{
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    //return Image Path to the Main Activity
                    Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                    returnFromGalleryIntent.putExtra("picturePath",picturePath);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnFromGalleryIntent);
                    finish();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG,"RESULT_CANCELED");
                Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
                finish();
            }
            break;
    }
}
   }
```

Please give the solution to display cropped image as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY` to  ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE.

or other suitable ScaleType such as `FIT_CENTER/CENTER_CROP/CENTER`.